# Area outside Navigation bar is not clickable in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uinavigationbar, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have created custom navigation bar and added one UIButton over it.

Please take a look at image attached.

[image]

I have UIButton with background image added as subview to Custom NavigationBar so portion above GREEN line is clickable not the portion below green line.

I have tried using **UITapGestureRecognizer** and also the **touches methods ie. touchesBegan** to UIImageView to handle the touch, but no luck.

I think this is only because my UIButton nontouchable potion is outside of NavigationBar Frame.

Is there any way to click the subview's portion which is ouside its parent view.

Comment: Can you paste your code ?

Comment: can anyone please guide me in my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The parent view size is less than the Child view . That's why it is non clickable. Asper my knowledge only option you have is try to increase the parent view (Custom Navigationbar) frame size .

Comment: thanks for quick reply. But i don't want to increase the parent view's height. Is there any other wayout.

Comment: No @BItBit . This is the only way we have as I know

Answer (score 0):

Yo need subclass Navigation Bar and add method `hitTest:withEvent:`. For example:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    CGRect extraTapRect = ...; // Put here needed rect
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(extraTapRect, point)) {
        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews.reverseObjectEnumerator) {
            CGPoint subviewPoint = [subview convertPoint:point fromView:self];
            UIView *result = [subview hitTest:subviewPoint withEvent:event];
            if (result != nil) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```